# Fixed Position Nav CSS3 Transitions / Hover Effects Not Working + Other Strange Bugs

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, css, responsive-design

https://4djustice.com

Issue 1 (FIXED):
Prior to scrolling the menu works fine with it's css3 transitions and hover effects and pseudo -selectors. However, when you scroll down, a fixed css class is added with jquery. When it's added, the menu starts behaving erratically (hovering doesn't work, dropdown menu is missing, etc.)

Issue 2 (FIXED):
There's a strange space below the footer and I'm not sure where it's coming from. I checked all the CSS, but it doesn't seem to be a margin, padding, or float issue.

This is coming from my plugin for the mobile nav menu. This is the code, which as I understand it, reads the height of the body and sets the #sb-site container to that height. However, I don't know why the height of the body extends past the footer.

```
// Inline CSS
    function css() {
    // Set minimum height.
        $site.css('minHeight', ''); // Reset minimum height.
        $site.css('minHeight', $('body').height() + 'px'); // Set minimum height of the site to the minimum height of the body.

    Some more code in the function that I don't think is relevant.

    }
```

Issue 3 (FIXED):
Fixed menus seem to be working on every page, except this one: http://justice.allureprojects.com/articles/public-defender-vs-private-attorney. This page has the same single.php template as any of the other articles.

BTW, I'm testing with the latest version of Chrome.

Thanks in advance!!

UPDATE (2/1/2017): All issues on the site have been fixed.

Comment: I'm using firefox, and I'm not able to replicate Issue#1. Issue#2 seems to be `sb-site`. Issue#3... the webpage throws an error, have you checked before? `TypeError: $ is not a function`

Comment: Why are you setting `minHeight`? Why can't you use `height:100%`?

Comment: @zgood I'm using the slidebars (http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/) script for my mobile menu (alternatives will be appreciated)...I've fixed the issue by manually changing the js of the slidebars script to read the height of the #content div instead of the body. I'm not sure why they create a function for the minHeight instead of setting  height to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Issue #1: Works in FireFox not Chrome. You need to show relevant code

Issue #2:  You have an inline style (`style="min-height: 2023px;"`) thats getting put on your `#sb-site` wrapper. Removing this fixes your footer problem.

It's probably getting put on there by a javascript plugin.

Issue #3: The fixed nav and side nav are both working fine for me on this page (Test: FireFox, Chrome, IE9+)

Comment: Which code should I show for Issue 1? The js or the css?

Comment: @AllureWebSolutions The js that initializes the menu and any custom css you have added would be great

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've taken a different approach completely. With it's hosts of issues.